# When does MLB use instant replay?

Tags: baseball, mlb, media, video-review

I was inspired to ask this question given instant replay was mentioned in this thread: [Why is FIFA against adding instant replay to the game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/179/why-is-fifa-against-adding-instant-replay-to-the-game)

For the 2012 season, has baseball changed any rules regarding instant replay?

Also, does the MLB use instant replay at all and in which cases do they use instant replay to review officiating?

Comment: Especially in the play-offs, IR needs to be implemented in close calls.Umpires after all are human.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_replay_in_baseball), the MLB has had instant replay since Aug. 28, 2008. It is used for determining:

- Fair (home run) or foul.
- Whether the ball actually left the playing field.
- Whether the ball was subject to spectator interference.

For the 2012 season:

> Instant Replay will expand to include fair and foul calls and balls that was [sic] caught, or trapped by the player catching the ball. It will also expand interference reviews beyond the home run boundary to all walls.

Answer (score 1):

Instant replay is also used to determine if a player is safe or out in close calls at a base or home plate. So according to Kevin's answer, it's used to determine fair or foul ball, whether the ball left the playing field, whether the ball was subject to spectator interference, plus the situation given by me above. My reference for the first part was my knowledge from watching countless hours of baseball on TV.