# Why do we have to wait for the goal line technology to be put into practice

Tags: football

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is FIFA against adding instant replay to the game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/179/why-is-fifa-against-adding-instant-replay-to-the-game)

After watching England's world cup match i was eagerly waiting for FIFA to introduce the goal line technology. But it hasn't come out yet.

What are the disadvantages of using it? In all other games now days technology is very much used and has resulted in a reduction of refereeing or umpiring errors.

What has FIFA got against the use of technology in the game?

Comment: Your question is a bit subjective - since nobody really knows the true answer to how long it will be (if ever) for goal line technology to be put in place. I would recommend editing your question to ask something that we can actually provide a good answer to. Otherwise it's just speculation.

Comment: I just titled the question as such. But I was asking about the drawbacks that fifa claim against it.

Comment: which drawbacks specifically? Are you talking about FIFA saying it will reduce the human element to the game and interrupt the flow of the game?

Comment: Yeah all those which they say against it.

Comment: This question is a poor fit for the SE engine. Its kinda forumy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the delays is the complexity of the technology and amount of testing that is currently being carried out. According to this [article](http://www.standard.net/stories/2011/10/09/soccer-not-set-get-goal-line-aids-until-2013), **9** different methods are currently being trialied.

As to why the governing bodies have been so against the introduction of this:

1. You may find this question useful; [Why is FIFA against adding instant replay to the game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/179/why-is-fifa-against-adding-instant-replay-to-the-game).
2. The bosses from up-high (Sepp Blatter and Michel Platini) have been very much against the introduction of such technology, even though [a survey](http://edition.cnn.com/2010/SPORT/football/03/05/football.fifa.goalline.technology/index.html) found 90% of players want it introduced, and you often hear managers expressing their interest in it as well.

   Sepp Blatter has been more sympathetic since the Frank Lampard goal during the 2010 World Cup against Germany, but Platini firmly believes "it would undermine the authority of referees and disrupt the natural flow of the game."
3. [Other critics](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/world-cup-2010/teams/england/7857951/England-v-Germany-Frank-Lampards-goal-reignites-goal-line-technology-debate.html) feel that the introduction of such technology "would impact on the human element of the game and remove the enjoyment of debating mistakes."
4. The cost of implementing such technology is high; especially for smaller clubs. It was thought that the introduction of more referees/ linesmen would be a cheaper and similarly effective alternative. This approach was [publically trialled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistant_referee_%28association_football%29#Goal-line_officials) in the UEFA Group League Stages 2009 - 2010, and was extended to the 2010 - 2011 stages as well.

Comment: Very well documented answers. Hope others could bring in more points.